# How to pass data from one app to another app without opening the latter?

Tags: android, android-activity, ipc

I want to trigger an application, B from application, A.

To achieve this i wrote the following in A

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.somepackage.appb");
intent.putExtra("secret", "message");
startActivity(intent);
```

However this opens up the application B which is not desired.

Please suggest a work around to avoid B from opening up and receive the data in background from application A.

Comment: **I want to trigger an application, B from application, A.**, **However this open up the application B which is not desired.** I am not getting what do you want?

Comment: assume it to be inter process communication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a `BroadcastReceiver` in application B and declare it in your manifest.

In application A, craft an intent with extras to target that receiver, and call `sendBroadcast` with that intent.

**Application B:**

*Manifest*

```
<application>
    ...
    <receiver android:name=".IncomingReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="jason.wei.custom.intent.action.TEST"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

*IncomingReceiver.java*

```
public class IncomingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String CUSTOM_INTENT = "jason.wei.custom.intent.action.TEST";
        if (intent.getAction().equals(CUSTOM_INTENT)) {
            System.out.println("GOT THE INTENT");
            Toast.makeText(context, "GOT THE INTENT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Application A:**

```
String CUSTOM_INTENT = "jason.wei.custom.intent.action.TEST";
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there are many ways to do this...myself i prefer creating a service which can update data without interacting with app B